# Does Buildbot support complicated build/deploy scenarios?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, toolchain

I need a tool/framework for CI/CD which can:

1. Support multi-repository project
2. Build and ship only changed part (frontend/backend) using revison hashes to decide
3. Ship some branches (release candidate brances) to test environment and some to production (master)
4. Get version number from repository based on branch name for RC
5. Get version number from repository based on last merged branch in master for production
6. Create build version in bug tracker and mark issues as fixed in created version based on issue status and planned version
7. Notify about new version uploaded on test/production with issues list from bug tracker
8. Get new database migration scripts (based on diff with previously uploaded version using revison hashes) and notify about them & (maybe) execute them

I wrote a script to do this but it lacks interface to do manual build/ship or to monitor build status (only notification at the end of build/deploy)

I have found Bouldbot but not shure it can handle these requirements.

If you know a framework which can handle these requirements without pain, please, name it.

Comment: I'm building Reliza Hub to support those points. It's early stage and not everything is implemented yet, but it's progressing quickly. The tool is completely free until the end of 2020. Site - https://relizahub.com, tutorial video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDlf5fMBGuI 
If you like the concept, book a demo with me - would be happy to help with your use case - https://calendly.com/pavel_reliza/demo

Comment: @taleodor thanks, but i need a mature CI/CD tool with documentation and community. Maybe later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins supports scripted pipeline which can handle my every requirement.
Buildbot can handle these requirements with custom steps, i suppose, but it's too hard if compared to Jenkins' scripted pipeline.